# Regex to match sentences with jumbled words but preserving sentence order

Tags: regex

I want to match sentences in such a way that words with the sentence can be any order but the sentences should be in same order.

e.g.

> My name is Sam. I love regex.

Acceptable input:

```
My Sam is name. regex I love.
name is My Sam. I regex love.
```

Invalid input:

```
I love regex. My name is Sam.
regex I love. is My name Sam.
```

sample regex I have come up so far to solve the above problem

```
^((?=.*\bMy\b)(?=.*\bSam\b)(?=.*\bis\b)(?=.*\bname\b))((?=.*\bregex\b)(?=.*\bI\b)(?=.*\blove\b)).*$
```

Which is not working as expected.

Can this problem be solved by regex? What would be the recommended approach to solve this?

**Note:** Please ignore `.` I am using it just for clarity.

Comment: Could you clarify what "word block" is? Can any other word appear there inside, e.g. "jack j. jules"? Why is `jules jason jack james` invalid if it contains "jack james"? Please [check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/xB6eX1/1).

Comment: So a `[]` consists of exactly one pair of words?

Comment: If our assumptions are correct, then maybe regex is not the best tool. Especially, if you have hundreds of such combinations.

Comment: Updated question with better example. Please review and provide your suggestions.

Comment: The rules are still not entirely clear.  Which part of the input string  do you want it to match?  The whole line?  The whole My/Sam/is sentence?  The other sentence?  Also, what are the rules for each of those sentences.  Does the sentence need to contain all of those words in order to be considered a match/non-match?  Or does the presence of just one of those words qualify?  What is the desired order of the sentences?  How do you determine where one sentence begins and ends?  Just any period, or does other punctuation count?  Can a period be in the middle of a sentence (e.g. "Mr. Smith")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't achieve with a single regex, instead I did the following:

- Virtually divided the sentence into multiple blocks.
- Maintained a sentence block -> regex configuration.
- regex configuration depends on the rule applicable on that sentence block.
- Applied the regex on the sentence to identify whether such block is existing or not.
- At last verifying whether the blocks are appearing in the configured order or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something else than regex. If you would want to do this, the most efficient way would be to compare an array of expected words and 'check' if they all appear once in a sentence. This is completely dependent on which context you are using. If you need a regex that literally finds what you stated in your example, you could use something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/vD3oR3/1):

```
/(My|name|is|Sam) (My|name|is|Sam) (My|name|is|Sam) (My|name|is|Sam)\. (I|love|regex) (I|love|regex) (I|love|regex)./g
```

But as you can see, this regex would grow exponentially the more words your sentence has. Also, it's really inefficient compared to parsing it with something else.